# Changing <path> attribute 'd' without using getElementBy... anti-pattern

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, angular-ngmodel

I have made a grid for a canvas in the context of an online "MS Paint"-like drawing platform. For the grid, the user must be able to input values for the size of the squares that make up the grid, as well as the opacity of the grid. I'm doing this using `ngModel`(for user inputs) and `ngStyle`.

Here is the part of the html code concerning the grid:

```html
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="smallGrid" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" [ngStyle]="setSizePattern()">
                <path id="myPath" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.7" [ngStyle]="setSizePath()" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>   
        <rect id="myGrid" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#smallGrid)" [ngStyle]="setStyle()"/>
    </svg>
```

`<pattern>` has attributes 'width' and 'height', and `<path>` has attribute 'd'; those are the attributes I'm looking to modify.

Here are the concerned methods:

```js
  setSizePath(): object {
      const pathString = '"M' + this.userInputGridSize + ',0 L0,0 0,' + this.userInputGridSize + '"';
      const cssPath = 'path(' + pathString + ')';
      return {d: cssPath};
  }

  setSizePattern(): object {
    return {width: this.userInputGridSize,
      height: this.userInputGridSize};
  }
```

The template `<path>` attribute `d` is `d="MX,0 L0,0 0,X"` where `X` is the size of the squares making up the grid. `width` and `height` of `<pattern>` also have to be `X`.

It **works** when I set it manually in the html file:

```html
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <pattern width="10" height="10" id="smallGrid" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" [ngStyle]="setSizePattern()">
                <path id="myPath" d="M10,0 L0,0 0,10" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.7" [ngStyle]="setSizePath()" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>   
        <rect id="myGrid" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#smallGrid)" [ngStyle]="setStyle()"/>
    </svg>
```

This displays a grid made of size 10 (px I think) squares.

I just can't seem to modify it.

In contrast, the `setStyle()` function found in `<rect>` works perfectly:

```js
  setStyle(): object {
    return {opacity: this.userInputOpacity};
  }
```

Oh and here's a unacceptable version (because of the getElementBy ... stuff) which also works:

```js
// Functional but code smell size setter

  setSizeSmell(): void {
    const gridElement = document.getElementById('smallGrid');
    const pathElement = document.getElementById('myPath');
    const value = (document.getElementById('sizeInput') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const pathValue = "M"+ value + ",0 L0,0 0," + value;

    if (gridElement && pathElement) {
      pathElement.setAttribute("d", pathValue);
      gridElement.setAttribute("width", value);
      gridElement.setAttribute("height", value);
    }

  }
```

`sizeInput` is the field where the user enters the desired value for grid square sizes. But we aren't allowed to use these methods because they are anti-pattern.

Comment: In some browsers a path's d attribute is not a style. I.e. not in Firefox and not (as far as I know) in Safari.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson thanks for answering. What other way could be used to modify the d attribute?

Comment: just bind to `d` directly using `[attr.d]="getStyle()"`. Here `getStyle()` returns `"M"+ value + ",0 L0,0 0," + value` i.e a string